# Is it possible to record INSERTed row references for deletion later?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, mstest

For testing I INSERT a bunch of rows into a SQLServer DB. I want to clear them up at the end.. while this should be a specific test-only database I want to be well-behaved just in case. For the same reason, I don't want to make assumptions on what data may already be in the DB when deleting my test data e.g. deleting all rows or all rows with dates in a certain range.

When inserting rows is there a way I can catch an reference to the actual rows inserted, so I can later delete those exact rows regardless if the data in them has been modified. So I know which exact rows I 'own' for the test?

I'm calling SQLServer queries from C# code within the ms-test framework.

Comment: What about using a temporary table to store those rows? Then delete from the database looking into your temporary table

Comment: I thinks this help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: This is interesting but is it possible to actually get a "row id" SQLServer uses to identify each row separately to my PK?

Comment: Yes, you can save those inserted PK value in table variable. @Mr.Boy

Comment: I recommend using a test framework such as tSQLt (http://tsqlt.org/). It provides all the necessary mechanisms for having a clean test environment for each test run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible with `OUTPUT` clause.

You need to create one intermediate table for capturing inserted records identity values.

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE(ID INT)

INSERT INTO TABLE1
output inserted.Table1PK into @TAB

SELECT id,name ... ETC
```

Now check your table variable

```
SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

If you want dump the Table variable data into one Actual table.

For more info look at [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Now you can delete the TABLE1 records like

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @TAB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transactions and rollback the transaction instead of committing the transaction at the end of your test.

You can do this with an explicit transaction, or by `set implicit_transactions on;` at the start of your session and not committing the transactions.

```
begin transaction test /* explicit transaction */

insert into TestTable (pk,col) values
  (1,'val');

update TestTable
  set pk=2 
  where pk=1;

select * 
  from TestTable 
  where pk = 2;

rollback transaction
--commit transaction
```

I wouldn't do this in a production environment because the transaction will hold locks until the transaction completes, but if you are testing combinations of inserts, updates, and deletes where the pk might change, this could be safer than trying to track all of your changes to manually roll them back.

This would also protect you from making mistakes in your tests that you aren't able to manually roll back.

Related: [How to: Write a SQL Server Unit Test that Runs within the Scope of a Single Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851217(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: Interesting. I'd failed to mention I'm doing this from C#. Any chance of an example (or someone else if you're not a C# guy)?

Comment: In the try section of [this example from SqlTransaction.Rollback Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayx5s0h(v=vs.110).aspx), you'd just use `transaction.Rollback();` instead of `transaction.Commit();`